# Change marker/color in 3D scatter plot based on condition

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to do a 3D scatter plot in Python with matplotlib where for example points > 5 are shown red and the rest is blue.

The problem is that I still get all values plotted with both markers/colors and I also know why this is the case but I'm not deep enough into Python thinking to fix this problem.

```
X = [3, 5, 6, 7,]
Y = [2, 4, 5, 9,]
Z = [1, 2, 6, 7,]

#ZP is for differentiate between ploted values and "check if" values

ZP = Z

for ZP in ZP:

    if ZP > 5:
        ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='r', marker='o')
    else:
        ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='b', marker='x')

plt.show()
```

Maybe the solution is also something I haven't learned yet but in my mind it shouldn't be hard to get this working.

Comment: Your `if` condition is not accomplishing anything- you're still plotting the entire series in both cases. Instead create separate `X` and `Y` for each condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make use of NumPy indexing. Since NumPy is already a dependency of `matplotlib`, you can use array indexing by converting your lists to arrays.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X = np.array([3, 5, 6, 7])
Y = np.array([2, 4, 5, 9])
Z = np.array([1, 2, 6, 7])

ax.scatter(X[Z>5], Y[Z>5], Z[Z>5], s=40, c='r', marker='o')
ax.scatter(X[Z<=5], Y[Z<=5], Z[Z<=5], s=40, c='b', marker='x')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create separate points for each condition:

```
X1,Y1,Z1 = zip(*[(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(X,Y,Z) if z<=5])
X2,Y2,Z2 = zip(*[(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(X,Y,Z) if z>5])

ax.scatter(X1, Y1, Z1, c='b', marker='x')   
ax.scatter(X2, Y2, Z2, c='r', marker='o')
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like this but wasnt able to get it working.
Thank you a lot :)